# Yearly Calendar - pop up when click on day

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, onclick

Some of you must recognize me from other posts I posted yesterday regarding issues I was having writing a calendar from scratch. Well, I have desisted, I think it is too difficult for my level as even with lots of resources I couldn't understand what was going on. So I've decided to grab a calendar already done, and add the functionality I need for my project.

It needs to be an event calendar, where the user clicks in a day ( from a table) and it opens that day and allows the user to write stuff, and when it click save, it will change the background color of that cell day.

Can anyone give me a hint about how to do it? Not the solution, but a guide to start! At the moment the only way I think is adding onclick function, but I don't think it's the best as I would need to add this function in every single  !!

Maybe I am completely wrong and it is not even possible... any clue will be appreciate it!

Thank you!

Comment: Does the input the user types on a day need to be accessible when they revisit the site? Or is it just a one-off type thing? This would likely affect the potential solutions.

Comment: yes!! it does!! Actually..... I haven't thought about it yet :S I thought first I need the functionality and then I will look for how to save it for next time they access. Oux :S it sounds it is going to be even more difficult than I thought! :S isn't it?

Comment: Well it might not be the easiest thing to implement, but it depends on how it needs to be done. Are you using any kind of CMS at all? If so you may find that there are premade modules for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all depends if you save call is using ajax, or a form post.

If its ajax you could have an id and class attribute for each calendar entry eg.

```
<div id="2015-october-14" class="clickable" />
```

Then you search in your javascript code using jquery for clickable class:

```
$("#clickable").onclick(function() {
    //here you find the element id defined above
    //and pass that id into the popup/modal thing you want
});
```

This means you only define onclick event once. If the content is dynamic you could start the search at the document: `$(document).on("click", "#clickable", function() {});`

For instance a modal could then show once clicked on a calendar entry and you can write and submit it. You then add a function to call ajax with the message and the html element id added in the example above. 
In the `$.ajax` function `onComplete` you can then search for the id of the html element eg "2015-october-11" and do whatever you need to do with it.

*If its a form post then you will have to just update it from server side to include the entries.*

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm going to give it a try. It sounds logical :)

Thank you!!